# function run error in wordpress add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to upload a photo for each post published in my host so I use WordPress action but it doesn't work.

When I use the function manually it works, but in action it doesn't.

```
 function post_photo_update($post_id){
        $imdb_id=vp_metabox('vp_meta_sample_8.imdb');
        $imdb=get_imdb_info('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='.$imdb_id);
        $html = file_get_html('http://tinymoviez14.com/'.$imdb_id);

        foreach($html->find('img[id=movie_picture]') as $element){
            $b=$element-> src ;
        }

        $url= 'http://tinymoviez14.com/'.$b;

        $f = fopen( 'image.jpg' , 'w+');
        $handle = fopen($url , "rb");
        while (!feof($handle))
        {
            $contents = fread($handle, 50000);
            fwrite($f , $contents);
        }
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($f);

        }
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'post_photo_update',10, 2 );
```

In other words, `image.jpg` file didn't upload when I published the post. All of the links and parameters have been checked and are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_action` call is specifying that the callback function takes 2 arguments, however, the function declaration only has 1 argument. Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/. By default, the `wp_insert_post` action uses 3 arguments (`do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );`, so this code should work:

```
<?php
function post_photo_update( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    // ...
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'post_photo_update', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I try this but still have problem. do not recieve any erorr just dont creat file

Comment: You're not required to have all 3 that are passed to `do_action`.

Comment: I just need to post_ID in future